# Sencha touch web app is loading very slow

Tags: sencha-touch

I have developed a web site using sencha-touch 2.4.1 but it takes a lot of time to load on mobile phone even I have to refresh many times.

Answer (score 0):

please specify that what you have create

```
production , testing or package.
```

i will suggest you for package because it'll take less time to start application then the other.
and other solution is that clear your cached data and load application
In case or production the code is minified and the resources like js and css file are compressed which are loaded more faster than the original one.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to create ios and android app

```
sencha cordova init your package name
cd cordova
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
cordova prepare
cd ..
sencha app build native
```

you can check your android and ios application in cordova/platform/android or ios

Comment: Thanxx  for your suggesstion Ravi but I am not building a native app... I am building a web site  in senhca touch and the loading issue is occurring there on loading.